# EndpointApi class gives error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

End point service class gives error-inside build-generated-endpoints package-

```
@Override
public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) {
  return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
}
```

Can't resolve method
I am using android studio with endpoint migration

Comment: Same here, I think its an android studio problem since it was working before I updated to the latest version

Comment: you got any solution for this or not

Comment: I upgraded the client libraries to 1.23 and it started working again

Comment: can u share ur app and backends buil.gradle plz

Comment: The fix is not in the backend, its in all the modules that use the backend

Comment: give me solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Endpoints Framework V2. I upgraded the google-api-client libraries from 1.22.0 to 1.23.0 in the app build.gradle and the backend build.gradle and the problem went away.

app build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'     
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
```

backend build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:1.23.0'
```

Comment: after these changes issue remains same for me

Answer (score 1):

In your endpoint project add this to *build.gradle*

```
appengine {
   endpoints {
      googleClientVersion = '1.23.0'
   }
}
```